# class of object with read_csv in R?

Tags: r

I wonder what class of object is dat.

I thought it's a data.frame, but I get another 3 classes. Can someone help with figure out this?

```
dat <- read_csv(datafile,col_types = cols(  
                                        player = col_character(),
                                        team = col_character(),
                                        position =  col_factor(),
                                        height = col_integer(),
                                        weight = col_integer(),
                                        age = col_integer(),
                                        experience = col_integer(),
                                        salary = col_double(),
                                        games = col_integer(),
                                        minutes = col_integer(),
                                        points = col_integer(),
                                        points3 = col_integer(),
                                        points2 = col_integer(),
                                        points1 = col_integer() )
            )

class(dat)
#[1] "spec_tbl_df" "tbl_df"      "tbl"         "data.frame"
```

Comment: Does this function come from package `readr`? You should include all non base packages you use in the question. More exactly, if your code uses contributed packages **start the script** with `libray()` calls.

Comment: it's a `tibble`. Given `read_csv` is a function within the `readr` package which in turn is part of `tidyverse`. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/vignettes/tibble.html